# Derivation Regression Factor Analysis

Tags: regression

can someone derive the last formula for the variance ?
I dont get the result and its in the script of my university:

"

(ii) Regression methodology: now assume the model $\mathrm{x}=\boldsymbol{\mu}+\mathrm{Lf}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$, such that
\begin{equation*}
\left[\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{x} \\
\mathrm{f}
\end{array}\right] \sim \mathcal{N}_{p+k}\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
\boldsymbol{\mu} \\
0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{LL}^{\prime}+\mathrm{V} & \mathrm{L} \\
\mathrm{L}^{\prime} & \mathrm{l}
\end{array}\right]\right) .
\end{equation*}

Then the conditional expectation $E[\mathrm{f} \mid \mathrm{x}]$ can be obtained as
\begin{equation*}
\hat{f}_R=L^{\prime}\left(L L^{\prime}+V\right)^{-1}(x-\mu)
\end{equation*}
using the result on the next slide. The variance of the estimator is given as
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{\mathrm{f}}_{\mathrm{R}}\right)=E\left[\left(\hat{\mathrm{f}}_{\mathrm{R}}-\mathrm{f}\right)\left(\hat{\mathrm{f}}_{\mathrm{R}}-\mathrm{f}\right)^{\prime}\right]=\mathrm{I}-\mathrm{L}^{\prime}\left(\mathrm{LL}^{\prime}+\mathrm{V}\right)^{-1} \mathrm{~L} .
\end{equation*}
"

Thank you in advance